# Documents with position info in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb with node.js. I had documents with location info, so the schema is

```js
{
  name: String,
  location: {
    x: Number,
    y: Number
  }
}
```

I want to get documents in certain distance from a point. So I need to calculate value of `x^2+y^2` and see if it's less than square of distance. Could you tell me how I can do that?

Comment: If you don't want to have native mongodb functionality for that, you will just extract all the docs and run the logic on each doc, selecting only those that apply to your formula

Comment: You can use MongoDB's native support for geospatial queries for this.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/

Answer (score 1):

So first thing is

```
{
  name: String,
  location: [
    x: Number,
    y: Number
  ]
}
```

location should be an array and then you can use $geonear

```
   db.places.find(
   {
     loc:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry : { type : "Point" , coordinates: [ 40 , 5 ] },
            $maxDistance : 500
          }
       }
   }
)
```

Its magical! Check out --http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/operator/query/near/

another example is...

```
db.places.find( { loc :
                   { $near : [ 40 , 5 ] ,
                     $maxDistance : 10
                } } )
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a geo index to that field